# Why doesn't this JList update to show ArrayList attributes

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, runtime-error, jlist

I have below a method that should display attributes of arrayList elements in a list when called:

```
public void updateList(){

    DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>)jCustomerList.getModel();

        for(User user: theUserList.Users){        
        model.addElement(user.getName());   

        jCustomerList.setModel(model); 

        }
}
```

however when it is called the following error appears :

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: supermarketiteration2.ShopJFrame$63 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel

How do I resolve this?

EDIT**

The model has been made global as shown below, however now the error occurs when instantiating the model:

```
public class ShopJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private UserList theUserList;
private User currentCustomer;
private Customer castedCustomer;
private SupplierList theSupplierList;
private DeliveryCompanyList theDeliveryCompanyList;
private ProductList theProductList;
private Product selectedProduct;
private Supplier aSupplier;
private DeliveryCompany aDeliveryCompany;
//private JList jCustomerList;

private java.awt.Component jTabInMemory1;
private java.awt.Component jTabInMemory2;
private java.awt.Component jTabInMemory3;
private java.awt.Component jTabInMemory4;
private java.awt.Component jTabInMemory5;
private java.awt.Component jTabInMemory6;

DefaultListModel<String> model;




    public ShopJFrame() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        initComponents();
    theUserList = new UserList();
    User currentCustomer = new Customer();
    Customer castedCustomer = null;
    theDeliveryCompanyList = new DeliveryCompanyList();
    aDeliveryCompany = new DeliveryCompany();
    theSupplierList = new SupplierList();
    aSupplier = new Supplier();
    theProductList = new ProductList();

    jTabInMemory1 = jMainTabbedPane.getComponent(1);//PRODUCTS
    jMainTabbedPane.remove(1);
    jTabInMemory2 = jMainTabbedPane.getComponent(1);//REORDER
    jMainTabbedPane.remove(1);
    jTabInMemory3 = jMainTabbedPane.getComponent(1);//SUPPLY CHAIN
    jMainTabbedPane.remove(1);
    jTabInMemory4 = jMainTabbedPane.getComponent(1);//CATALOGUE
    jMainTabbedPane.remove(1);
    jTabInMemory5 = jMainTabbedPane.getComponent(1);//MY ACCOUNT
    jMainTabbedPane.remove(1);
    jTabInMemory6 = jMainTabbedPane.getComponent(1);//MY ACCOUNT
    jMainTabbedPane.remove(1);

    theProductList.loadFromFile(theProductList.getFilename());
    theSupplierList.loadFromFile();
    theDeliveryCompanyList.loadFromFile();
    theUserList.loadFromFile();
    theProductList.displayReorders(jProductReorderTextArea);

    this.updateComboBox("Supplier");
    this.updateComboBox("Delivery Company");
    this.updateComboBox("Products");
    model = (DefaultListModel<String>)jCustomerList.getModel();
    jCustomerList.setModel(model);
```

Comment: `list.toArray()` creates a ***copy*** of the original list - there is no binding in the code you are showing.

Comment: oh, what is the syntax to bind?

Comment: Please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swing a [*model*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) is passed to the JComponent.

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
jCustomerList = new JList<String>(model);

model.addElement("Albert Einstein");
...
```

_(The later JavaFX has *observable* data types, a bit more like *binding* as you intended.)_

Now one should neither create a new JList or ListModel.

```
public void updateList() {

    DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<>)jCustomerList.getModel();
    model.addElement("Madame Curie");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, please see my edit as it is still showing the default list.

Comment: Extended the answer: Your updateList will never assign to the variable passed to its call. In java `f(x)` will never change the variable `x`. Then the JList already exists and is layout in its JFrame, so should not be created anew and added to its parent. The same holds for the model.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: supermarketiteration2.ShopJFrame$63 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ on the line     -----------------------------------------                                                                  DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>)jCustomerList.getModel();

Comment: This JList must first have a DefaultListModel set. Maybe better make one global `model` field, set it in the JList, and immediately alter the field.`model`.

Comment: I am so sorry but I have made it global and it is still giving the same error.  I will show in edited question.